# dotnetopenauth: where are the web samples

Tags: .net, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I downloaded dotnetopenauth last week and I have seen people mention the samples, but all I see is a desktop sample.  Where would I find a web/asp.net sample?

Sad, I don't know if I should post another question, but I really meant the linq2twitter web samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a LinqToTwitterWebFormsDemo folder included with the LinqToTwitter source code available on CodePlex.  I don't know if it's included in the .zip download.  But if not you can find it online.

Answer (score 0):

In the samples directory - it's nearly all web based samples.

This is the package you want: https://www.ohloh.net/p/dotnetopenauth/download?package=DotNetOpenAuth&release=3.4.3

Comment: Link doesn't work (samples I found for DotNetOPenAuth didn't work either, and assumed a lot of knowledge)

Comment: Well it certainly used to work when I posted the comment - try here, samples directory: https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid